# Duplicity and GPG: charset conversion

Tags: character-encoding, gpg, duplicity

I'm using duplicity on OS X Mavericks.

If I run my duplicity command, I get the following error:

```
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: conversion from `US-ASCII' to `utf-8' failed: Illegal byte sequence
gpg: “0DB243EE”: skipped: public key not found
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: public key not found
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

The strange thing is that the backup command worked until recently.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I always ran duplicity with the --encrypt-key=“XXXXXXXX” option. But for some reason I have to run it without "=" and the quotes. The correct syntax is: --encrypt-key XXXXXXXX.